# Compute rolling skewness and kurtosis in sas quickly for a very large data set

Tags: sql, performance, sas

I have the following code to compute the skewness on a rolling window of returns:

```
libname backup 'C:\Users\Anwender\Desktop\backup sas data';

data crsp_daily;
set backup.crsp_daily;
run;

proc sort data=crsp_daily;
by permno date;
run;

data crsp_daily1a;
set crsp_daily;
lastofmonth = last.month;
by permno year month;
run;

proc sql;
create table roll_ret as
select h2.permno, h2.Date, h1.retadj as lagret
from crsp_daily1a as h1,
crsp_daily1a as h2
where h1.permno = h2.permno
and intck("MONTH",h1.date,h2.date) between 0 and 11
group by h2.permno, h2.date
having count(h2.permno)>250 and h2.lastofmonth = 1
;

quit;

proc means data = roll_ret noprint;
by permno date;
var lagret;
output out=crsp_daily_final skew=skewRet kurt=KurtRet;
run;
```

The input data set has a daily date variable, from which I have already constructed a year and month variable. It also has an ID for the stock (permno) and daily returns (retadj).I want to compute rolling skewness from all observations from the last year, but only if there are at least 250 observations in this window. I am only interested in results for the last of the month.

The Input data set has more than 60 million!!! observations, the above code is simply too slow. I have already tried to work with a view instead of an data set for roll_view without improvement.

How can I quickly compute a rolling skewness in the above sense for this very large data set?

General comments on my code would be appreciated as well.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you tried to profile the code?

Comment: How would that work? Could this provide a solution how to speed things up? The main challenge comes from the proc sql, which creates a huge data set, is there a way around this step?

Comment: Simple profiling in SAS can be done using options fullstimer and examining the log (SAS also provides the script to extract this info http://support.sas.com/rnd/scalability/tools/fullstim/). I see, you already know the bottleneck :), will post some suggestion on optimization in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

PROC SQL performs heuristic analysis of the potential join strategies, you can review it by using proc sql _method option. Potential user optimization strategies are outlined here (http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts553.html). Probably, your case falls into the category of join of a small (h2) and large (h1) datasets - creating an index on the key usually helps in this case.

Comment: Thank you for this advice, so you would suggest creating an index on permno in both data sets? Would running the following code before the sql join do the job: proc sql; create unique index permno on crsp_daily1a; However, I am not really dealing with ohne small and one large data set, actually they are the same, thus having the same size. Would this still be a reasonable step?

Comment: @Kostya, there is some great stuff at that link that was new to me.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3575894 Apologies, couldn't come back earlier. Unfortunately, optimization depends on the structure of your data. But the main idea is simple: reduce the sizes of the datasets before forming the cartesian product. Maybe, if you can post a log of proc sql _method, we can suggest something more specific

Comment: Sorry for coming back late. Creating an index did not speed things up significantly. The following code works very well, but as mentioned before, speeding things up here might be data set specific. What helped in my case was to use a view instead of a data set and temporary arrays.

Comment: Here is the code I am now using:

data rwin /view=rwin;
array _Y {250} _temporary_ ;
set crsp_daily1;
by permno;
retain N 0;
N = ifn(first.permno,1,N+1);
I = mod(N-1,250)+1;
_Y{I} = retadj;
if (N >= 250 and lastofmonth) then do I = 1 to 250;
lagret = _Y{I};
output;
end;
run;

proc means data = rwin noprint;
by permno date;
var lagret;
output out=crsp_daily_skew_kurt skew=skewRet kurt=KurtRet;
run;